# How to bring a job to the front of the build queue?

Tags: jenkins

I currently have hundreds of builds in the build queue.  It will take several days for them all to be built.

I want to bring a specific build to the front of the queue to have it build next.

Currently, the only way I have of doing that is to kill all of the other jobs in the build queue and then re-trigger them.

It seems that surely there must be a better way.

Is there?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no such built-in functionality.
Please, have a look at the jira issue: [Ability to move job to top of queue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1878)

Although, there is a plugin which seems like a possible solution for you: [Accelerated Build Now Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Accelerated+Build+Now+Plugin)

> The Jenkins Accelerated Build Now Plugin allows Jenkins users to launch a project's build right away, even if the queue is long (moving it to the top of the queue) and even if no executor is available (killing and rescheduling builds not launched by "humans")

Comment: It looks like you cannot prevent this plugin from killing jobs.  I don't want to kill any jobs -- I just want my job to scheduled next

Comment: @BobRoberts I think it's achievable with [Priority Sorter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin will help you : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Accelerated+Build+Now+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

https://plugins.jenkins.io/simple-queue/ is a plugin that allows changing a build queue order from UI manually. And it seems to be a viable solution in 2022.

[image: 1]